# Resize iframe height to fit content (without access to the iframe id)

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I know similar questions have been asked before, but all solutions that have been given in the past required access to the iframe id.

I am embedding a script that generates an iframe upon page load and also generates a fresh iframe id each time. Unfortunately the content is also highly dynamic and the content often changes dramatically, so a fixed height solution is just not going to cut it.

Looking for a solution to fit iframe to content height on page load without the need of an iframe id.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your `iframe` to load always in a known tag, e.g:

```
<div id="myIframe">
  <iframe id="I-have-no-idea-what-is-the-id"></iframe>
</div>
```

And then, you can do in your CSS:

```
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#myIframe > iframe {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  border: 0;
}
```

Comment: Although this does target the iframe, it didn't successfully detect the height of the iframes content.